# How to apply convolutional neural network over a time series of Landsat images

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, regression, google-earth-engine-python-api, tensorflow

I am implementing a fully convolutional neural network (specifically U-Net) over a time series of Landsat 8 images to predict land cover change. I am following the [demo notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/UNET_regression_demo.ipynb) for the predictions. However, this notebook only trains CNN over a single image (using median over multiple years) to predict single image output of impervious surface.

What I want is **to input multiple months of imageries for training to predict the respective monthly land cover change (that varies spatio-temporally)**.

I have found `Dataset.window()` that can create windows from a time series of datasets ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55429307/2503949)), but have no idea how can it be implemented for my case of time series of Landsat imageries.

Any ideas or examples where this is implemented?

Comment: Maybe `imageCollection.toBands()`?